# How to create navigation property for columns that do not have same table name ID

Tags: entity-framework, api, .net-core

I'm trying to set-up a one-to-many relationship between table `users` and `orders`, but the issue is that `Users` table does not have a foreign key that can be linked to table `Orders`, and the column I'm referring to is `orderNumber`

The app has been in production for a while, so trying to either add or change the columns is not an option.

The goal is to use what already exists and make this async function work by following navigational property approach.

```
public async Task<List<Order>> GetCustomerOrders()
{
    using (var context = new Users())
    {

        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.orderNumber == 7005);
        return user.Orders.ToList(); 

        /* Error
           An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

           ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
           Parameter name: source
        */

    }
}
```

And the model classes look like this:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int orderNumber { get; set; }

    /* Create relationship with orderNumber foreign key */
    [ForeignKey("orderNumber")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

}

public partial class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int orderNumber { get; set; }

   /* Create relationship */
   public virtual User User { set; get; }

}
```

Comment: What columns in the _database_ relate a User and an Order?  If a User has a single orderNumber FK value, how can a user have multiple Orders?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I'm not sure if I truly understand your question, but I'll try to answer. The column does not have any foreign key that relates User and Order such as `oderID` in User table. And for that reason, I want to use `orderNumber` as a one-to-many relationship. I'm following this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) for using `foreginKey` to change the FK to `orderNumber`. I'm guessing that the context query is not fully right, or maybe I'm doing something that is not even possible.

Comment: Can you post the database table definitions for the tables and explain how they are related.